# Fit new value range of driver to 0-1

Tags: scripting, rigging, drivers, shape-keys

I'm making a new facial rig and I'm using the x location value as a driver for the shape key.
I want to fit my x value in the driver between 0-1, does anyone have any suggestions.

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify by telling us what 'the' x location is.  X location of what, exactly?

Answer (score 2):

((driverValue) - startMin)/(startMax - startMin) * (endMax - endMin) + endMin

Answer (score 0):

In the Driver Editor, the  f-curve graph, instead of controlling the map from `frame` on X to `property` on Y as it does in animation,  controls the map of `driver input` on X to `driver output` on Y.

So your driver might look like this:

[image]

.. by moving the control points, you can change the offset and ratio of input value to output value. The relationship does not have to be linear.

And the curve can take modifiers. Here, to clamp the output value between -5 and 5. (That could be 0-1, in your case.)

[image]

So, in this example, this is the result of red X driving blue X ....

[image]